# Using a function with an reactive argument for generating a table

Tags: r, shiny

my aim is to create a reactive table (tab.11) using the renderTable which is structured as follows (sorry for my english...):

1. the data.frame "malprof" contains the fields "Year", "ASL", "ATECO_Macro", "ATECO_2cfr" and "ATECO_2cfr"
2. inputId$ASL has 4 values, "TOSCANA", "ASL CENTRO", "ASL NORD-OVEST", "ASL SUD-EST"
3. inputId$Anno has all the possible values stored in "Year" field of the data.frame
4. in tabPanel "XI Reports for Sector of Productive Activity" there is a radioButton with the inputId "levelAteco"
       with values "Sections", "2 digits", "Complete" (the names of the 3 fields)
5. a table is generated by the function tab.l1() through the switch command which, depending on the value of inputId$levelAteco, activates one of the functions
       tab.11.a (), tab.11.b () and tab.11.c ()
6. the final command output$tab_11 <- renderTable({tab.11(input$Year)}) should display the table by taking input$Anno as the argument of tab.11().
       but the console displays the error:

   Listening on http://127.0.0.1:5457
   Warning: Error in tab.11: unused argument (input$Anno)
   Stack trace (innermost first):
       79: renderTable [C:\Users\Gianpaolo\Desktop\ReportMalprof_ShinyApp\App/app.R#129]
       78: func
       77: origRenderFunc
       76: output$tab_11
        1: shiny::runApp

and the app:

```
"Error: unused argumenti(input$Anno)
```

This is the code, could you tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
require(shiny)
require(dplyr)
require(reshape2)
require(stringr)
require(shinythemes)

#load("App/dati.RData")

load("dati.RData")

#### UI ####
ui <- fluidPage(
  theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
  fluidRow(column(2, selectInput(inputId = "Anno",
                             label = "Anno di manifestazione",
                             choices = as.list(unique(malprof$Anno)),
                             selected = max(malprof$Anno),
                             multiple = FALSE)),
           column(2, selectInput(inputId = "ASL",
                             label = "Territorio",
                             choices = list("TOSCANA", "ASL CENTRO","ASL NORD-OVEST","ASL SUD-EST"),
                             selected = "Toscana",
                             multiple = FALSE))),
  titlePanel("Elenco tabelle"),
  navlistPanel(

  #### Tab XI ####
  tabPanel(title = "XI. Segnalazioni per Settore di Attivita' Produttiva",
           h3(textOutput(outputId = "tab_11_text"), style = "font-size:100%"),
           radioButtons(inputId = "livelloAteco",
                    label = "Livello Ateco",
                    choices = list("Sezioni", "2 cifre", "Completo"),
                    selected = "Sezioni",
                    inline = TRUE),
           div(tableOutput(outputId = "tab_11"), style = "font-size:80%")
           )
     )
)

#### SERVER ####
server <- function(input, output) {

  fargs <- list(big.mark=".", decimal.mark=",") 

  # ASL
  rg <- filter(malprof, ASL == "TOSCANA")
  no <- filter(malprof, ASL == "ASL NORD-OVEST")
  se <- filter(malprof, ASL == "ASL SUD-EST")
  ce <- filter(malprof, ASL == "ASL CENTRO")

  selezioneASL <- reactive({switch(input$ASL, 
                                    "TOSCANA" = rg,
                                    "ASL CENTRO" = ce,
                                    "ASL NORD-OVEST" = no,
                                    "ASL SUD-EST" = se)})



  #### Tabella XI - Distribuzione delle segnalazioni per Settore di Attivita' Produttiva ####


  # Livello ATECO
    tab.11.a <- function(x){
                tabella <- selezioneASL() %>% filter(anno == x) %>%
                group_by(ATECO_Macro, nesso) %>%
                summarise(N = n()) %>%
                dcast(ATECO_Macro ~ nesso, value.var = "N", fill = 0, sum, margins=TRUE)

                tabella$ATECO_Macro <- as.character(tabella$ATECO_Macro)
                tabella$ATECO_Macro[nrow(tabella)] <- "TOTALE"

                perc_pos <- round(tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`1 - Positivo`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                perc_seg <- round(tabella$`(all)`/tabella$`(all)`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                rapp <- round((tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`(all)`)*100, digits = 1)
                tabella <- data.frame(tabella, perc_pos, perc_seg, rapp)
                tabella <- tabella %>% select(ATECO_Macro, X.all., perc_seg, X1...Positivo, perc_pos, rapp)

                names(tabella) <- c("ATECO", "Casi segnalati", "%", "Casi con nesso  positivo", "%", "Rapporto tra positivi e segnalati")
                tabella
            }

    tab.11.b <- function(x){
                tabella <- selezioneASL() %>% filter(anno == x) %>%
                group_by(ATECO_2cfr, nesso) %>%
                summarise(N = n()) %>%
                dcast(ATECO_2cfr ~ nesso, value.var = "N", fill = 0, sum, margins=TRUE)

                tabella$ATECO_2cfr <- as.character(tabella$ATECO_2cfr)
                tabella$ATECO_2cfr[nrow(tabella)] <- "TOTALE"

                perc_pos <- round(tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`1 - Positivo`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                perc_seg <- round(tabella$`(all)`/tabella$`(all)`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                rapp <- round((tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`(all)`)*100, digits = 1)
                tabella <- data.frame(tabella, perc_pos, perc_seg, rapp)
                tabella <- tabella %>% select(ATECO_2cfr, X.all., perc_seg, X1...Positivo, perc_pos, rapp)

                names(tabella) <- c("ATECO", "Casi segnalati", "%", "Casi con nesso  positivo", "%", "Rapporto tra positivi e segnalati")
                tabella
            }

    tab.11.c <- function(x){
                tabella <- selezioneASL() %>% filter(anno == x) %>% 
                group_by(ATECO_completo, nesso) %>%
                summarise(N = n()) %>%
                dcast(ATECO_completo ~ nesso, value.var = "N", fill = 0, sum, margins=TRUE)

                tabella$ATECO_completo <- as.character(tabella$ATECO_completo)
                tabella$ATECO_completo[nrow(tabella)] <- "TOTALE"

                perc_pos <- round(tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`1 - Positivo`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                perc_seg <- round(tabella$`(all)`/tabella$`(all)`[nrow(tabella)]*100, digits = 1)
                rapp <- round((tabella$`1 - Positivo`/tabella$`(all)`)*100, digits = 1)
                tabella <- data.frame(tabella, perc_pos, perc_seg, rapp)
                tabella <- tabella %>% select(ATECO_completo, X.all., perc_seg, X1...Positivo, perc_pos, rapp)

                names(tabella) <- c("ATECO", "Casi segnalati", "%", "Casi con nesso  positivo", "%", "Rapporto tra positivi e segnalati")
                tabella
            }  

    tab.11 <- reactive({
                selezioneLivelloAteco <- switch(input$livelloAteco,
                                                "Sezioni" = tab.11.a,
                                                "2 cifre" = tab.11.b,
                                                "Completo" = tab.11.c)
                        })                                     

    output$tab_11 <- renderTable({tab.11(input$Anno)},
                                 display=c("s","s","d","s","d","s","s"),
                                 spacing="s",
                                 align = "lccccc",
                                 na="--", format.args=fargs)  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: how large is the data frame ? you should use `dput(malprof)` and `dput(inputId)` to copy paste the dataframe here so that any one who wants to help has an idea what you are working with.

Comment: the data.frame is 79585 records and 42 variables, I've uploaded it on Drive: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1C36QLIgkkjAR7QXgf0E1ztKiU-x38LE9

Comment: `tab.11(input$Anno)` makes no sense. `tab.11` is a reactive conductor and it doesnt' have arguments. Moreover it returns nothing.

Comment: Any suggestion...? I think the main problem is the where to using input$anno.